# Zero-one links: how many, and how to produce?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

For $m \geq 1$, define a **link** to be a zero-one word $w=d_0d_1 \ldots d_k$, where $d_0=0$ and $k=2^m-1$ , such that the words

$$ w_0=0^{m-1}d_0, w_1=w_0d_1, w_2=w_1d_2, \ldots, w_k = w_{k-1}d_k $$

include as subwords every zero-one word of length $m$.  How many links are there, and how can they be produced?  If the answer is known, all I need is a reference.  Otherwise, the question extends naturally to links of words on the alphabet from $0$ to $n>1$.

**Example:**  For $m = 3$ two links are $01011100$ and $01110100$.  The first link codes the following words: 
$$w_0 = 000, w_01, w_010, w_0101, w_01011, w_010111, w_0101110, w_01011100, w_010111000, $$
in which all $8$ zero-one words of length $3$ occur as the final $3$ letters of the words.  (The final word, $w_010111000$, is shown as the first word in a second link in an infinite chain.)

Comment: Have you tried small values and searched OEIS?

Comment: Editor - can you fix the first display line?  It looked just right when I submitted it.

Comment: DeBruijn sequences?  Gerhard "Sure I've Seen This Before" Paseman, 2015.11.20

Comment: here is the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence